# erro "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma página em php para editar arquivos, aonde você escreve o nome em um input e seleciona a extensão por um select, na hora da conversão ele acontece o erro "Array to string conversion". (Segue o código para analise).

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){

    if(isset($_POST['ext'])){
     $arquivo = "./Arquivos/".$_POST['nome'].".".$_POST['ext'];
     } else{
     $arquivo = "./Arquivos/".$_POST['nome'].".".['extension'];
     }
     $fp = fopen($arquivo,"w");
     $fw = fwrite($fp,$_POST['texto']);  
     fclose($fp);
     include $arquivo; 
  }
```

Comment: Os primeiros 2 casos do fechamento se referem ao problema em si, o terceiro é uma solução caso queira usar múltiplos arquivos/nomes. Se nenhum resolver seu caso, queira [edit] a postagem acrescentando o respectivo código de envio, e a linha exata do erro. Se realmente não for um caso coberto pelos links apontados, a reabertura do post pode ser considerada.